# Not getting ConnectionString correctly

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a project with multiple layers:

- Client (WindowsForms)
- WebLayer (asmx webServices)
- Business
- Data (Works with dataTables)

In Data layer I have the ConnectionString defined in Settings, but I want this Connection to be overrided in the WebLayer. I tried to override it putting the same in the Web.config, but it doesn't seems to work. It still uses the config from the Business layer

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="aaa.bbb.ccc.Business.Properties.Settings.ExampleConnectionString"
     connectionString="DataSource=xxxxxx"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Another thing that I want to ask is that I can't debug the .asmx. When I create the object from the Facade, it automatically changes it to a Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy object, and when I try to access the code of the implementation of a method, it doesn't allow me.

Comment: Do you need the config-level override in first place ? This kind of problem is better solved at programatic level - i.e. having IConnectionStringProvider and DI container that will return it; bootstrap DI container differently for data layer and for web application.

Comment: Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy - client does not automatically switch debugging context to server ;) you need to attach debugger to server process instead.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Changing it to do it programatically is not really an option right now. It is a pretty big application and I was asked to change only the config just to avoid publishing in case of a change of the server of the database.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Related to the transparentProxy, I can access the code of the WebService layer (attaching as you say to the other process) but what I can't do is debugging the bussiness layer. I don´t know if it can affect, but both cliente a WebService are referencing this layer.